# Jayway JsonPath read String Java

Tags: java, jsonpath

I receive an array of JSON objects, a part of which is below:

```
[{"Team":"LTD","Amount":10000.0,"Success":true},
 {"Team":"XYZ","Amount":50000.0,"Success":false}]
```

I want to forcefully read all fields as string so as to make further processing easy and uniform. So `Amount` must be read as `10000.0` and not as `1.0E5`.

Below is the code snippet that I use :

```
String input=IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
String[] fields="Amount|Success".split("\\|");
ReadContext inputParsed =JsonPath.parse(input);
List<JSONArray> resultList=Arrays.stream(fields)
                          .map(x -> inputParsed.read("$[*]."+x,JSONArray.class))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
//Further code to process resultList
```

When I print the values and type of `Amount` from `resultList`, they are shown as `1.0E5` and `String` respectively. In between parsing and reading, the conversion from `Double` to `String` seems to occur in unexpected way.

I read a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51300567/jayway-jsonpath-read-long-java) and it addresses a bit different problem.

The `inputStream` and `fields`, which are to be extracted , will be provided at run time. Hence, using POJO and other methods that need to define Class won't work.

Comment: just so you know, `String.split(..)` takes `RegEx` as a parameter, so you should escape the pipe, like `"Amount|Success".split("\\|");` Otherwise, it is just a boolean `or`.  For your problem, where are you seeing it is shown as `1.0E5`?  You might just need to print it using `String.format("%.1f", val)`

Comment: You can also use `Double.toString(val)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. You should download **org.json.jar**  this is used to convert json to what you need(String,int,etc), 
 2. Change your json format like below i mentioned
```

**JSON :**

```
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "Team":"LTD",
         "Amount":10000.0,
         "Success":true
      },
      {  
         "Team":"XYZ",
         "Amount":50000.0,
         "Success":false
      }
   ]
}

public static void main(String[] arg) throws JSONException {
        String arr = "{  \n"
                + "   \"data\":[  \n"
                + "      {  \n"
                + "         \"Team\":\"LTD\",\n"
                + "         \"Amount\":10000.0,\n"
                + "         \"Success\":true\n"
                + "      },\n"
                + "      {  \n"
                + "         \"Team\":\"XYZ\",\n"
                + "         \"Amount\":50000.0,\n"
                + "         \"Success\":false\n"
                + "      }\n"
                + "   ]\n"
                + "}";

        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(arr);
        JSONArray data = obj.getJSONArray("data");
        int n = data.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            final JSONObject dt = data.getJSONObject(i);
            System.out.println(dt.getString("Team"));
            System.out.println(dt.getString("Amount"));
            System.out.println(dt.getBoolean("Success"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: The inputStream and fields, which are to be extracted , will be provided at run time. Sorry but the suggested method does not look efficient.